# ¿Cómo simpificar consulta MySQL múltiples con COUNT, alias y WHERE en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla en MySQL llamada 'miembros' a la que me gustaría contabilizar el total de los grupos de valores contenidos en la colunma llamada 'categoría'. El siguiente php funciona, pero ¿hay una forma de simplificarlo en una sola consulta?

```
<?php
    include('conexion.php');

    $registros = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM miembros");
    $resultado_rec = $registros->fetch_object();

    $caballeros = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(categoria) as tc FROM miembros WHERE categoria='c'");
    $resultado_c = $caballeros->fetch_object();

    $damas = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(categoria) as td FROM miembros WHERE categoria='d'");
    $resultado_d = $damas->fetch_object();

    $jovenes = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(categoria) as tj FROM miembros WHERE categoria='j'");
    $resultado_j = $jovenes->fetch_object();

    $adolescentes = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(categoria) as ta FROM miembros WHERE categoria='t'");
    $resultado_a = $adolescentes->fetch_object();

    $ninos = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(categoria) as tn FROM miembros WHERE categoria='n'");
    $resultado_n = $ninos->fetch_object();

    $bebes = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(categoria) as tb FROM miembros WHERE categoria='b'");
    $resultado_b = $bebes->fetch_object();

    $viejos = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(categoria) as tv FROM miembros WHERE categoria='a'");
    $resultado_v = $viejos->fetch_object();
?>
<section>
    <h3>BALANCE</h3>

    <p><?php echo $resultado_rec->total ?> Registros totales.</p>
    <p><?php echo $resultado_c->tc ?> Caballeros.</p>
    <p><?php echo $resultado_d->td ?> Damas.</p>
    <p><?php echo $resultado_j->tj ?> Jóvenes.</p>
    <p><?php echo $resultado_a->ta ?> Adolescentes.</p>
    <p><?php echo $resultado_n->tn ?> Niños.</p>
    <p><?php echo $resultado_b->tb ?> Bebés.</p>
    <p><?php echo $resultado_v->tv ?> Ancianos.</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres los totales de todas las categorías:

```
SELECT categoria, count(*) AS tc FROM miembros GROUP BY categoria
```

Te devuelve una fila por categoría. El total de miembros lo puedes calcular en PHP sumando los resultados de cada categoría.

Si quieres los totales de solo algunas categorías:

```
SELECT categoria, count(*) AS tc FROM miembros WHERE categoria IN ('a', 't') GROUP BY categoria
```

En este caso si además quieres el total de todos los miembros tendrás que realizar otra consulta.